# How to deploy my distributed system dynamically on Docker or other clusterization technologies?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose

I have a distributed architecture service with an orchestrator and different types of worker services. Works can be clustered with different configs or the same. So I want to deploy my worker services dynamically. Like reading a JSON configuration from the console or a web service that contains the specifications of workers and deploying them based on the incoming JSON.

I want the simplest way if there is any. First Docker, docker-compose, and then if there is no solution in those technologies using Kubernetes, IAC.

Comment: (Both core Docker and Kubernetes have HTTP APIs which sound not unlike what you're describing.)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be to write your own `bash` script to start the environment but it will get hard to maintain the moment you have non trivial services or require infrastructure provisioning.

If you are going with Kuberentes you can think about [GitOps](https://about.gitlab.com/topics/gitops/):

> GitOps is a branch of DevOps that focuses on using Git code repositories to manage infrastructure and application code deployments. The main difference between the two is that in GitOps, the Git repository is the source of truth for the deployment state, while in DevOps, it is the application or server configuration files.

One option here is [ArgoCD](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), a declarative, GitOps continuous delivery tool for Kubernetes.

Comment: it was a good starting point